# Плавающий ImageView, расположенный поверх ListView

Tags: android, java

Добрый день.

Возникла необходимость зафиксировать элемент (пусть это будет ImageView), который должен располагаться поверх ListView и оставаться на одном и том же месте (нижний правый угол) во время его прокрутки.

Аналог видел у evernote - зеленая иконка "+" для раскрытия выпадающего списка.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое реализовать в проекте?

Comment: Спасибо!! Если ответите на вопрос, отмечу как правильный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это называется Floating Action Button, а дальше все просто. нужно немного погуглить

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а если у ListView и FAB общий родитель RelativeLayout, то когда ListView небольшой (в пределах высоты экрана), то кнопка корректно отступает от нижнего и правого угла, а когда высота ListView больше высоты экрана, то кнопка прилипает к низу... как это исправить?

Comment: RelativeLayout и ListView сделать match_parent

Comment: Спасибо, действительно у родителя (и всех других родителей) нужно поставить match_patent.